# knockout observables dont seem to be created?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a project and i just started from scratch again to have a clear mind about what was going wrong. Now that i'm re doing it i realise my knockout observables aren't really working and i dont know what is the problem.

This is my app.js

```
var places = [
{
    title: 'Cafe Mondegar',
    location: {
        lat: 18.9241,
        lng: 72.8321
    }
},
{
    title: 'Four Seasons Hotel Mumbai',
    location: {
        lat: 18.9971,
        lng: 72.8184
    },
},
{
    title: 'Gokul',
    location: {
        lat: 18.923100,
        lng: 72.832244
    }
},
{
    title: 'Grand Hyatt Mumbai',
    location: {
        lat: 19.0774,
        lng: 72.8513
    }
},
{
    title: 'Irani café',
    location: {
        lat: 19.063644,
        lng: 72.862288
    }
},
{
    title: 'Kohinoor Square',
    location: {
        lat: 19.0249,
        lng: 72.8415
    }
},
{
    title: 'Leopold Cafe',
    location: {
        lat: 18.9227,
        lng: 72.8317
    }
},
{
    title: 'Oberoi Trident',
    location: {
        lat: 18.927,
        lng: 72.8204
    }
},
{
    title: 'Punjabi Chandu Halwai Karachiwala',
    location: {
        lat: 19.042690,
        lng: 72.863337
    }
},
{
    title: 'The Table',
    location: {
        lat: 18.924121,
        lng: 72.833116
    }
},
{
    title: 'The Taj Mahal Palace Hotel',
    location: {
        lat: 18.9217,
        lng: 72.8330
    }
},
{
    title: 'Watson\'s Hotel',
    location: {
        lat: 18.9283,
        lng: 72.8311
    }
}
];

var viewModel = {

places: ko.observableArray(places),
num: ko.observable(34),
name: ko.observable('pankti')

};
console.log(viewModel.places[0]);
console.log(viewModel.num);
console.log(viewModel.name);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And this is my html

```
<body>
   <ul class="title" data-bind="foreach: places">
       <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="location"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The `console.log(viewModel.places[0])` returns `undefined`.

```
console.log(viewModel.num) returns 
ƒ c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ua(c[F],arguments[0])&&(c.ia(),c[F]=arguments[0],c.ha()),this;a.l.sc(c);return c[F]}
```

where am I going wrong ?

Comment: you load you app.js before loading knockout, so can correct that first...

Comment: so i changed it, but its not working.

Comment: You are not binding anything in your HTML. You should go through 
 the documentation for [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding and search for examples on stackoverflow and google. This is a basic implementation.

Comment: i tried that as well. the thing is the observables are not being created. console.log() statements should at least give the expected output right ?

Comment: `observables` are functions. To [read an observable's](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) value you need to call it like this `console.log(viewModel.num())`. Update the question with what you have tried with `foreach` binding.

Comment: @adiga it worked :) thank you so much..this happens to me all the time. i'll overlook something small but important and get lost. thanks :)

Comment: `places` is also an observable, thus a function and should be called as such: `viewModel.places()[0]`